# Invert selection in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets. Below you can see codes and data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('max_columns', None)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'type_sale': ['group_1','group_2','group_3','group_4','group_5','group_6','group_7','group_8','group_9','group_10'],
         'id':[70,20,24,80,20,20,60,20,20,20],
        }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['type_sale',
                                      'id',])


data = {'type_sale': ['group_1','group_2','group_3'],
         'id':[70,20,24],
        }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['type_sale',
                                      'id',])
```

These codes created two datasets that are shown below :

[image: df1]

[image: df2]

Now I want to create a new data set df3 with values from df1 that are different (distinct values) from the values df2 in the column `id`.

The final results should as pic below

[image]

I tried with these codes but are not giving desired results.

```
df = pd.concat((df1, df2))
print(df.drop_duplicates('id'))
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as follows:

- Use [`df.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to check for each value in `df['id']` whether it is contained in `df2['id']`.
- Next, invert the resulting boolean `pd.Series` by using the unary operator `~` (tilde) and select from `d1`.
- Finally, reset the index.

In a one-liner:

```
df3 = df1[~df1['id'].isin(df2['id'])].reset_index(drop=True)

print(df3)

  type_sale  id
0   group_4  80
1   group_7  60
```